# can any one please let me know about ratings and reviews of appstore?

Tags: ios

> In Itunes, I got 248 ratings for my app, but still it is showing only 6 rating in appstore.Can any one please let me know about ratings and reviews of appstore???

Comment: Maybe you are just seeing the rating for current version? App Store shows current rating and all ratings separately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the inner workings of Apple and not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is directly linked not only with rating, but also with installs, uninstalls and commentaries.

It's really easy to find about on Google, but here you have a link that explains it really clear: https://moz.com/blog/app-store-rankings-formula-deconstructed-in-5-mad-science-experiments

Comment: thanks for your answer